# friend function in global namespace with custom return type

Tags: c++, namespaces, clang, friend

I'd like to make a friend function of a class from a global namespace, which seems to work fine, unless the friend function uses a custom return type like this:

```
typedef int Type;

Type myFunction();

namespace foo {

class Foo
{
 public:
    friend Type ::myFunction();

 private:
    void bar() {}
};

}

Type myFunction()
{
    foo::Foo a;
    a.bar();
    return 0;
}
```

If `int` is used instead of `Type` the code compiles, but with the `typedef` the compiler does not seem to separate the type from the namespace, and gives an error:

```
error: expected a class or namespace
        friend Type ::myFunction();
               ^
error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
        friend Type ::myFunction();
```

I'm using clang++ 500.2.79 on OS X.
I could use `#define` instead of `typedef` as a workaround in the example, but in my real-world issue the custom type is coming from another header file, which cannot be changed.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Compiles fine [at least at Ideone (GCC)](http://ideone.com/5wLR5y). Really seems to be a [clang specific problem](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d7ccf99e0ca5d1b).

Comment: Same problem for me with gcc 4.9.2-6, awesomeyi's answer solved it for me..
Is this a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works in GCC, but doesn't work in VS13, or as you said, in clang++. However, this fixed the problem in VS13:

```
friend Type (::myFunction());
```

Comment: Thanks! Works in clang++ as well.

Comment: Seemingly `friend Type (::myFunction)();` also works.